# For a single page application including data, is it better to have data in json,html or xml?

Tags: javascript, html, xml, json, dom

I am going to create a single page application which will be a dictionary of 32,000 terms. This needs to be single page as it will be used by a very non-tech public and there can be no installation procedure.

I currently have the data in xml format. The xml format is

```
<word>
    <text>The word</text>
    <guide>Prononciation</guide>
    <class>Adjective / verb etc.</class>
    <defn>html content containing the definition of the word</defn>
</word>
```

32,000 of these, the total xml size is 16Mb.

Only one  word will be shown at a time, i.e. there will be a search box with auto-complete that will lead you to a word, you hit enter and the word information is displayed.

My question is : from a browser performance perspective, am I better off converting the data to json, html (i.e. `<div class="word"> <div class="text"> etc`, ) or xml ? The size of the individual json/html/xml files that I have created are all pretty similar.

Are references to explained the proposed data format would be appreciated also ?

Best regards,

Colm

Comment: I don't understand the question. Are you asking whether HTML is the best way to create an HTML page?

Comment: Either way you still need to _parse_ that data to JavaScript objects, so pick whatever is faster (JSON parsing is native in most browsers). Do not attempt to have all the HTML generated and just show/hide portions. Having a DOM that large will probably trash performance.

Comment: @SergiuParaschiv a table with 32000 rows, of which 31999 hidden, will perform fine in any current browser on any current computer. Having said that I suspect he just wants 'JSON', or rather an inline JS object.

Comment: You're not going to make your users download a 16 meg dictionary to lookup a single word are you? Really? ;)

Comment: @Niels Keurentjes just tested this and you are perfectly correct. `document.getElementById('line-100')` in a 32000 row table runs in one millisecond, the same as a 200 row table, so DOM size has no penalty.

Comment: @carbontracking It is pointless to come up with figures until you have designed *in detail* how your software is going to operate. For instance, you mentioned autocompletion. You got figures now for `getElementById` but it is unlikely that `getElementById` would be useful to match words *partially*. (Note: not *impossible* but *unlikely*.) Ultimately the impact of the *algorithm* that will search the database for partial matches, and the presence or absence of indexes to help this search, will most likely eclipse the impact of the choice between JSON, HTML or XML on performance.

Comment: JSON could be native in JScript like this: var dict=[{text:"The word",
guide:"Prononciation",
class:"Adjective / verb etc.",
defn:"html content containing the definition of the word"}, ...] or even associative array like this were you can index by your favorite item - text here: {"The word":{
guide:"Prononciation",
class:"Adjective / verb etc.",
defn:"html content containing the definition of the word"}
} - ex. x["The word"].guide . But better to have keys in quotations as class, etc. could be reserved words.